# SQLite AUTOINCREMENT column counter behavior with ON CONFLICT IGNORE clause

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

When creating a small app using SQLite I've noticed a strange thing (for me) with autoincrement columns counter algorithm behavior.

For instance, let's try to create database with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (num INTEGER UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

and a small Python script

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cur = con.cursor()

def values():
    for i in xrange(1, 3):
        yield (i,)
try:
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO numbers (num) VALUES (?)', values())
except sqlite3.DatabaseError, err:
    print u'Error: ', err
else:
    con.commit()
    print u'Number of added rows: %d' % cur.rowcount

cur.close()
con.close()
```

Let's run script for three times. Last time with different values() output, xrange(3,5) for example. So, we get output

```
Number of added rows: 2
Number of added rows: 0
Number of added rows: 2
```

Ok, then let's check our database and everything seems as it should

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3 'select rowid, * from numbers'
1|1
2|2
3|3
4|4
```

Then try to create database with adding an autoincrement alias to system rowid column.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, num INTEGER UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

Then do the same thing as above and check the rows.

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3 'select rowid, * from numbers'
1|1|1
2|2|2
5|5|3 <- sqlite jumped over intermediate counter values for rowid and id column
6|6|4
```

SQLite saves intermediate counter values for rowid and alias autoincrement column when using IGNORE constraint voilation resolution algorithm for a table and skips them when assigning a new autoincrement value. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

1. sqlite sees that a `ROWID` has not been specified and generates one. For regular `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` cases it's basically `MAX(ROWID)+1`. For `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` cases a new number that has never before been used is picked from the special `sqlite_sequence` table. This table holds the table `name` and `seq` value for autoincrement row ids.
2. An insert is attempted. The unique constraint is violated so the `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` resolution takes place. Effectively nothing is done and no error is raised. However, altering `sqlite_sequence` was still successful and will be committed once the transaction completes.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html